# Pulling from a database and displaying with c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm just starting out with server side code and Visual Studio with C#, but something I can't figure out with my googling is how do people use C# and Visual Studio to access a database and pull results and display them on the html documment?

I have an SQL Server 2012, I believe I know how to connect to the database itself, but unless I use classic ASP I don't understand how to pull it from the database and display it using C# and or ASP.NET.

Comment: I, myself, used this before: www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial.. It's a bit long to explain all of it in an answer.

Comment: [ASP.NET tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/introduction-and-overview)

Comment: @JonathanLin No. ASP.NET is a suite of web application frameworks. C# is a programming language. You can use C# (and several other languages) in ASP.NET projects.

Comment: try learning basic ADO.NET using this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/361579/A-Beginners-Tutorial-for-Understanding-ADO-NET)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you start out with [Ado.Net](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet).  Once you have a good understanding of the principles, look into Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1):

Robin Nadeau is right, what you'll probably want to start with is Ado.Net controls. In reference to your example, how I would go about it is using a DataGridView and binding it with a BindingSource + DataSet. When you drop a DataGridView on the form, it will give you a chance to run through a wizard to easily set up the BindingSource and Dataset.

To filter stuff from there, you'll need to hook up the buttons etc. with code such as this:

```
bindingSource1.Filter = string.Format("VideoTitle LIKE '{0}'", txtSearch.Text);
```

Hopefully that helps you get started.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner and don't have enough time to learn a complete framework. I would suggest to use the WebMatrix.Data Wrapper. Life's simple with it. 6 Commands is all you need to know to make 90% of the applications. Just install the Nuget Package and you're good to go.

Those 6 Commands are

**1. Open & Close Connection**

```
var db=Database.Open("name of connection string in web.config");
db.Close();
```

**2. SELECT Query**

```
foreach(var row in db.Query("SELECT * FROM tablename")
{
servervariable1=row.column1;
}
```

**3. SELECT Single Row**

```
var row=db.QuerySingle("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE Key=@0",PassedVariable);
if(row!=null)
{
// do the operation
}
else
{
// handle code if the row is not found
}
```

**4. SELECT Single Value**

```
try{
datatype variable=db.QueryValue("SELECT columnname FROM tablename WHERE Key=@0",Key);
}
catch{
// handle code if row doesn't exists
}
```

**5. INSERT Query**

```
db.Execute("INSERT INTO tablename(column1,column2) Values(@0,@1)",inputvar1,inputvar2);
```

**6. DELETE Query**

```
db.Execute("DELETE * FROM tablename WHERE Key=@0",key);
```